# Arraylist and Jframe

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans

I'm having issues with `arrays` in this project. I have to save all the students and teachers on their respective classes, and, on this case specifically, I need to be able to add teachers and delete them from their respective classes, along with showing the info for each class. `AulasColegio` is an `ArrayList` where I store all the classes, and Profesores the same with the teachers. The thing is, adding classes to the `ArrayList` in the main class, I think it doesn't show them on the `JFrame`. All my problems have to do with where to add the teachers and classes, and how to make them be on the `JFrame` also, and vice versa. I would really appreciate some solution.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class ventDirector extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form ventDirector
     */

    public ventDirector() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtClase = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        bttInfoClase = new javax.swing.JButton();
        bttAlta = new javax.swing.JButton();
        bttBaja = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtProfesor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtClaseProfesor = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        bttAtras = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Información clase");

        txtClase.setText("Introduzca nombre de la clase");

        bttInfoClase.setText("GO");
        bttInfoClase.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                bttInfoClaseMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        bttInfoClase.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bttInfoClaseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        bttAlta.setText("Alta profesor");
        bttAlta.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                bttAltaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        bttAlta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bttAltaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        bttBaja.setText("Baja profesor");
        bttBaja.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                bttBajaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        txtProfesor.setText("Nombre profesor");
        txtProfesor.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtProfesorActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtClaseProfesor.setText("Nombre clase");

        bttAtras.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/sudoku/back-arrow_icon-icons.com_72866 (1).png"))); // NOI18N
        bttAtras.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        bttAtras.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                bttAtrasMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        bttAtras.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                bttAtrasActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(92, 92, 92)
                        .addComponent(bttAlta)
                        .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                        .addComponent(bttBaja))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(txtClase, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(bttInfoClase))
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(txtClaseProfesor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(txtProfesor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 95, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addComponent(bttAtras, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(74, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(txtClase, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(bttInfoClase))
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(txtProfesor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(txtClaseProfesor, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(bttBaja)
                    .addComponent(bttAlta))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(bttAtras, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(17, 17, 17))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void bttInfoClaseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                            

    private void bttInfoClaseMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        boolean flag =false;

        for(int i =0; i<aulasColegio.size();i++){
            if (aulasColegio.get(i).getNombreClase() == txtClase.getText()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, aulasColegio.get(i).getNombreClase()+ "\n" +
                    aulasColegio.get(i).getProfesores()+ "\n" + aulasColegio.get(i).getAlumnos() + aulasColegio.get(i).getNumAlumnos());
            flag =true;
            }
        }
        if (flag = false) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No existe la clase");

    }                                         

    private void txtProfesorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void bttAltaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                       

    private void bttAltaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        boolean flag =false; 

        Profesor profe = new Profesor(txtProfesor.getText());
        for(int i =0; i<aulasColegio.size();i++){
            if (aulasColegio.get(i).getNombreClase() == txtClase.getText()){
                aulasColegio.get(i).anadeProfesor(profe);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Añadido con éxito");
                flag =true;
            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No es esta clase");
        }
        if (flag = false) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ese profesor no se encuentra en la clase");
    }                                    

    private void bttBajaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        boolean flag =false;

        for(int i =0; i<aulasColegio.size();i++){
            if (aulasColegio.get(i).getNombreClase() == txtClase.getText()){
                for(int j = 0; j<profesores.size(); j++){
                    if (profesores.get(j).getProfesor() == txtProfesor.getText()){
                        aulasColegio.get(i).eliminaProfesor(profesores.get(j));
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Eliminado con éxito");
                        flag= true;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        if (flag = false) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Ese profesor no se encuentra en la clase"); 

    }                                    

    private void bttAtrasActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void bttAtrasMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        login_1 L = new login_1();
        L.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ventDirector.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ventDirector.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ventDirector.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ventDirector.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ventDirector().setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }
    private ArrayList<Clase> aulasColegio  = new ArrayList<Clase>();
    private ArrayList<Profesor> profesores  = new ArrayList<Profesor>();

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton bttAlta;
    private javax.swing.JButton bttAtras;
    private javax.swing.JButton bttBaja;
    private javax.swing.JButton bttInfoClase;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtClase;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtClaseProfesor;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtProfesor;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The main class is not finished.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class SudokuNino {

  private String nombreColegio;
  private String nombreDirector;
  private ArrayList<Clase> aulasColegio = new ArrayList<Clase>();
  //private Partida[] partidas;

  public void SudokuNiño(){};

  /*EXCEPCION  */ 
  public void SudokuNiño(String c, String d){
     this.nombreColegio= c;
     this.nombreDirector= d;
 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        SudokuNino main = new SudokuNino();
        Clase clase1 = new Clase("girasoles");
        main.aulasColegio.add(clase1);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never add something in your list `aulasColegio`. The reason is simple. 
When you start the main from the class `ventDirector` it opens the GUI like you want. On each button event you have the following for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i<aulasColegio.size();i++){
    ...
}
```

This for loop will never run if the ArrayList is empty! And it is always empty. The same with profesores. I don't see a single `profesores.add()` or `aulasColegio.add()` in the whole code of yours. So of course nothing happens. The code is running as intented.

In case of the class `SudokuNino`. It creates some object and finish but nothing else happened. Don't know why you add this code piece.

Some hints:

1. Use english. Don't use other language in coding this will help others to understand your code as well. I don't know how `ñ` will affect the code but I can say for sure I would never program in German (my native language)
2. Use System.out.println() to debug your code or the debugger from your IDE this can help you a lot in understanding your code. You would have seen that your array is always empty. You have to add somehow some elements first before you can iterate through it.
3. Instead of `==` in String comparison (or Object comparison) you have to use `equals`:

   ```
   String test=new String("hello");
   String test2=new String("hello");

   System.out.println(test == test2);
   System.out.println(test.equals(test2));
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   false
   true
   ```

Comment: I should´ve updated this but yes i debugged after trying some other stuff but actually the problem was on the if comparison, because i tried after with an equals and then it worked, even though i still have the same doubts about where to create my objects Clase, Profesor and those to be able to use it on other classes. Thank you and yes my intention was to translate the code for everyone to understand it but i was on a rush.

Comment: @LauraGlez ah yeah String comparison always should be done with equals. In general all Object comparison should be done with equals because == compare reference. Didn't check that because it already failed with an empty Array.

Comment: @LauraGlez the question where to create that is always a tough design question and always depend on what you want to achieve. There are a few patterns which might help you like the MVC pattern.